# FreeNAS 9.2.1.7 cannot start CIFS

Tags: windows, freenas, cifs, afp

I have a FreeNAS server running and I got AFP for my Mac working but whenever I try to start CIFS, I get an error at the top of the screen saying the service cannot be started. I've searched the Internet but cannot find the solution for my particular problem.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have shares set-up on cifs before starting the service and if that doesn't work...

You will need to go take a look at the logs... You will need to use coreFTP or open a shell window to browse the NAS (this will require you to set-up SSH on FreeNAS and get CoreFTP to talk to FreeNAS). You then need to browse to "/var/log" (in the root of your nas) and find the log which gives you more info on your problem...